# .next() jquery function skips next sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a class from an element and add that class to the next element. The problem is that the next element gets skipped. Here is my Javascript:

```
var $active = this.$view.find('.active');
if ($active.index() !== this.$view.children().length - 1) {
    $active.next('.list-group-item').addClass('active');
    $active.removeClass('active');
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div>
     <a class="list-group-item active">1</a>
     <a class="list-group-item active">2</a>
     <a class="list-group-item active">3</a>
     <a class="list-group-item active">4</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is `this.$view` ? Can you explain briefly with your code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.list-group-item').on('click',function(){
    debugger;
    var $active = $(this).parent().find('.active');
    if ($active.index() !== $(this).parent().children().length - 1) {
        $active.next('.list-group-item').addClass('active');
        $active.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.active{
    font-weight:bolder;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <a class="list-group-item active">1</a>
     <a class="list-group-item ">2</a>
     <a class="list-group-item ">3</a>
     <a class="list-group-item ">4</a>
</div>
```

Hi i think you are trying to achieve this as i understand by you code

here is the jsfiddle

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7cntxzdx/3/)

points that are first

- **.active** class is given to the all  tags.
- then after you are **finding the  tag's children element** that you will never get coz it's not having.

i have corrected your desired code my way you will change it with your prospective work

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your intention. But some things that might help:

The last `$active.removeClass('active');` removes the `active` class from all elements that `$active` points to. That means that the `$active.next('.list-group-item').addClass('active');` line is basically meaningless.

the `next()` method will search elements matching the selector immediatly *after* the first element in `$active` and so - the first one would be skipped. You can use `siblings()` if you want also to work on the first element.

The `index()` method would return 0 as long as you have a at least 1 element pointed by `$active` regardless of the length of that collection. The condition you evaluate seems strange in that regard.